# What are the risks associated with Russia collapsing?

Tags: russian-federation, international-relations

[European Pravda](https://www.eurointegration.com.ua/eng/news/2022/04/7/7137384/) presents the Russian Federation's collapse as inevitable in the next few years, the invasion of Ukraine acting as a catalyst for it:

> In his 2016 essay *Will the Russian Federation Make it Past 2031?
> Russia, China, and the Inevitable Consequences of Climate Change*,
> Mesík postulated that Russia’s collapse will become the main theme of
> the next decade. However, Russia’s incursion into Ukraine has
> dramatically changed the events. Mesík now believes that the demise
> will take place in the next 3-5 years.

The same article presents a series of benefits from the neighbors' perspective:

> Once it has collapsed, territories like Crimea and Donbas will return
> to Ukraine, Abkhazia and Southern Ossetia – to Georgia, Transnistria –
> to Moldova. This goes without saying, notes Mesík.

The author also urges that this should be a very important topic on West's agenda in the near future:

> The West must start analyzing Russia’s collapse scenarios because of
> **the risks** and opportunities. After all, Europe and the West risk
> repeating the mistakes they made following the USSR’s demise.

Some of the benefits were already mentioned, so I will focus on the risks. The main risk I can see is securing of the nuclear weapons.

What are the risks of Russia collapsing besides the nuclear one?

Comment: While I don't disagree that this is something we would like to know, I am skeptical that an answer that isn't wildly speculative about this future scenario (really myriad sub-scenarios) is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, a frame challenge: You can't talk about the risks of a military event while *completely* ignoring the military risks. And military does by definition include nuclear. It's only a fragile framework of agreements and mutual threats that keeps them from being used.

Pope Innocent II tried to ban archery, but the ban didn't last long - any party would rather face global condemnation than lose their war. Crossbows were too big an advantage to give up. The gap between nuclear and conventional weapons is much wider, closer to that of assault rifles against rocks and clubs.

As it stands, Russia's *standing conventional army* has proven insufficient for conquering a similarly armed country 1/3 the size. Russia's *total forces*, including naval, air, and missile, still exceed the rest of the world, excepting the US and Russia.
[The US has 5,600 warheads, Russia 6,300, the rest of the world about 1,200](https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/nuclear-weapons-by-country). This power will not vanish, it will get into someone's hands.

When the Soviet Union was being disbanded, great care was taken to keep the entirety of its nuclear weapons within the most stable of its successor states, specifically Russia. While often referred to as a "collapse" today, at the time it was a four-year series of diplomatic arrangements, which included a [series of agreements](https://nsarchive.gwu.edu/briefing-book/russia-programs/2018-03-16/nato-expansion-what-yeltsin-heard) between the parties, and specific treaties for nuclear disarmament of each post-Soviet state other than Russia.

A deeper collapse would not provide for the same level of care regarding the handling of strategic armaments, nuclear and otherwise.

At this moment, the Russian state is highly stable and authoritarian. It would take a major black swan event to cause its collapse. The invasion of Ukraine was a black swan event for almost everyone, *but not for Putin*. He's been preparing for it for 8 years, and the harsh response to the invasion [strengthened, not weakened his grip on the country](https://www.usnews.com/news/world-report/articles/2022-03-31/putins-support-strong-in-russia-amid-ukraine-war-poll).

Returning to the question's frame, should such a collapse occur, the example of the 1990s indicates that some of the risks that *may or may not materialize* include:

- Russia's Muslim republics, such as Chechnya and Dagestan, might split off for good. These have fundamentalist Islamist movements.
- The unrecognized republics supported by Russia have previously been engaged in wars with or without that support. These wars are likely to resume.
- Russia has a strong military/police junta called the [Siloviki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silovik), which may survive intact or split, but not disappear.

The rest of the consequences will depend on whether the Siloviki stay in one piece or split into multiple factions.

If they stay together, a military dictatorship will form in current Russia's place, minus possibly Chechnya. It's not clear what it might do next.

If they split into factions, there will be multiple nuclear states where Russia currently is. Due to the nationwide nature of these factions, it's likely that the split will not be entirely territorial, but more akin to a gang war scenario, where most territories have multiple factions present, and spheres of influence are informal and dynamic.

The factions will not be equal in power. Russian strategic forces [rely on central launch codes](https://nuke.fas.org/guide/russia/c3i/), and only one of the factions will get them. On the other hand, a lot of tactical weapons don't require any central authority to use. [At least 2,000 are estimated to exist](https://sgp.fas.org/crs/nuke/RL32572.pdf).

While "tactical" might sound like "small", modern tactical weapons tend to be [around Hiroshima strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tactical_nuclear_weapon). Even a small number of such weapons, used correctly, can quickly deplete a non-nuclear state of sustained warfighting ability.

The key feature of tactical weapons, making their use more likely, is that it isn't *necessarily* subject to MAD, since they don't register on ICBM warning radars. Any response to them would be considered through political channels, rather than a drilled military response.

It's unlikely that the resulting factions would attack other parts of Russia proper. It's too dangerous and too unpopular. It's very likely that they would instead form alliances with, take over, and prove their strength in various post-Soviet states and contested territories. Ones that were already in conflict before the collapse would be the most likely targets for displays of power.

Since all of the factions would likely be unrecognized states, if states at all, they would only have to worry about direct military response, not sanctions.

When empires fall, a lot of dominoes follow. The end of the Soviet Union was only a half-fall, perhaps comparable to Rome's split into Eastern and Western empires. Still, the 1990s were the [third-highest peak decade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_conflicts_in_Europe#21st_century) for conflicts in Europe, after the 1910s and the 1940s.

P.S. Again, due to the nature of the question, none of this is certain. It's impossible to predict the exact series of events. I've tried to map out the possible branches based on historical precedent.